# Query Genérica com PredicateBuilder e Linqkit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Eu venho usando [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) para criar queries genéricas há um bom tempo.

Uma coisa que sempre me incomodou é o fato de ter de testar sempre se o valor enviado no filtro é válido.

Por exemplo: Suponha que eu tenha um filtro por strings. As condições podem ser Equal, StartsWith, EndsWith e Contains.

Meu método seria mais ou menos o seguinte:

```
public List<MyModel> Get(MyModelFilter filter)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.prop))
    {
        predicate = predicate.And(_myModel => myModel.Prop.Contains(filter.prop));
    }

    // mais uma gigante quantidade de if's com vários filtros

    return DbSet.AsExpandable()
            .Where(predicate)
            .ToList();
}
```

Para acabar com este monte de If's, eu resolvi criar um método genérico para aplicar o filtro nas propriedades.
Minha ideia é passar a propriedade onde o filtro será aplicado, e a definição do filtro, e encapsular a lógica de criação da Expression

Ficaria algo do tipo

```
public List<MyModel> Get(MyModelFilter filter)
{
    predicate = predicate.And(_myModel => myModel.Prop, filter.PropFilterDefinition);
    // adeus If's, apenas as outras implementações de filtros

    return DbSet.AsExpandable()
            .Where(predicate)
            .ToList();
}
```

Para isso, eu criei alguns métodos de extensão para cuidar disso

```
public static Expression<Func<TPredicate, bool>> And<TPredicate>(
    this ExpressionStarter<TPredicate> predicate,
    Func<TPredicate, string> property, StringFilterDefinition filter,
    bool ignoreNull = true)
{
    if (InvalidStringFilter(filter, ignoreNull))
    {
        return predicate;
    }

    // este é o And do LinqKit
    return predicate.And(BuildPredicate(property, filter));
}

private static Expression<Func<TPredicate, bool>> BuildPredicate<TPredicate>(
    Func<TPredicate, string> property,
    StringFilterDefinition filter)
{
    if (filter.Filter == StringFilterComparators.Equal)
    {
        return x => property.Invoke(x) == filter.Value;
    }

    if (filter.Filter == StringFilterComparators.BeginsWith)
    {
        return x => property.Invoke(x).StartsWith(filter.Value);
    }

    if (filter.Filter == StringFilterComparators.EndsWith)
    {
        return x => property.Invoke(x).EndsWith(filter.Value);
    }

    return x => property.Invoke(x).Contains(filter.Value);
}

private static bool InvalidStringFilter(
    StringFilterDefinition filter, 
    bool ignoreNullValue = true)
{
    if (filter?.Filter == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return ignoreNullValue && string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Value);
}
```

O problema é que o filtro não é aplicado, e a resposta está no Invoke logo ali em cima. O EF não consegue traduzir a expressão acima para SQL.
O erro do EF é

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory[8]
>   The LINQ expression '(__property_0.Invoke([x]) == __filter_Value_1)'
>   could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.  To configure
>   this warning use the DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings API 
>   (event id 'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning').
>   ConfigureWarnings can be used when overriding the 
>   DbContext.OnConfiguring method or using AddDbContext on the
>   application service provider.

A pergunta é:

Como posso fazer para que esta construção funcione?
Além disso, Alguma sugestão de como melhor isso?

Comment: +1 pelo Linqkit =)

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido.

O grande segredo é que o LinqKit possui outras features realmente úteis, como o AsExpandable, Expand e Invoke.

Por conta destes métodos, é possível combinar expressões sem ter problemas.

Porém, estes itens funcionam apenas com `Expression<T, R>`

Assim, basta substituir `Func<T, R>` por

```
private static Expression<Func<TPredicate, bool>> BuildPredicate<TPredicate>(
    Expression<Func<TPredicate, string>> property,
    StringFilterDefinition filter)
{
    if (filter.Filter == StringFilterComparators.Equal)
    {
        return x => property.Invoke(x) == filter.Value;
    }

    if (filter.Filter == StringFilterComparators.BeginsWith)
    {
        return x => property.Invoke(x).StartsWith(filter.Value);
    }

    if (filter.Filter == StringFilterComparators.EndsWith)
    {
        return x => property.Invoke(x).EndsWith(filter.Value);
    }

    return x => property.Invoke(x).Contains(filter.Value);
}
```